# Criteria Query: search By Id and IDs of other associated entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have these 3 entities

```
public class Car {
    private Person owner;
    private SalePerson lastSaler;
}


public class Person {
    private Long id;
}


public class SalePerson {
    private Long id;
}
```

and I want to query with a CriteriaQuery the Car with an ID, but ALSO adding the conditions:
owner with a certain ID
salePerson with a certain ID.

Comment: I suppose I have to bind all conditions with criteriaBuilder.and(predicate1, predicate2).

Answer (score 0):

```
session.createCriteria(Car.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("owner.id", ownerId))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("lastSaler.id", salerId));
```